# Set<String> Sort and remove specific value

Tags: android, sorting, sharedpreferences

i'm looking for this problem for hours.
I have autocompletetextview which is shows the all inputs in dropdownlist.
I keep values in Sharedpreference.

```
AutoCompleteTextView texttutar;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences pref;
Set<String> hs;

ONCREATE ----

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = pref.edit();
    hs = pref.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    texttutar.setAdapter(adapter);

 if(!texttutar.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
     hs.add(texttutar.getText().toString());
     editor.clear();
     editor.putStringSet("set",hs);
     editor.commit();
                        }
   //    SortedSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<String>(hs);
   //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + sortedSet.first(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//    if(hs.size()>=5)
//    hs.remove(hs.iterator().next());    Removing last value of hs

                        adapter.clear();
                        adapter.addAll(hs);



  texttutar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                       adapter.getFilter().filter(null);
                        texttutar.setThreshold(1);

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        texttutar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                texttutar.showDropDown();
            }
        });
```

Now, this code works perfectly.
But i need two more things to do.

First problem : When i add values like

100 - 101 - 102 - 103 -104 - 105

its showing me the values like that :

102 - 100 - 105 - 103 - 101 - 104

I dont know why. It must sort by time.

Second problem : As you can see i can remove the last value but i didnt find any solution for first item.

I tried something like Treeset but its not important. Important is i should delete the value of Set (Sharedpreference).

After autotextview shows 5 value, it must delete the first item.

Like that : I'm adding this values. 110-200-300-400-690 and then 900

When i add 900 the code must remove the first value (110 ) then first value will be 200 . Its work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are unsorted.  THe definition of a Set is that it keeps track of a group of items and that you can test quickly whether an item is in it or not (typically in O(log n) or O(1) time).  There is no promise of order, and in fact a set usually uses balanced binary trees or a hash internally, purposely losing order for speed.

For what you want, a Set is not the appropriate data structure.  You want a queue.  A queue is an ordered group of items where you add them to one side and remove from the other.  Particularly it seems like you want a fixed size queue.  I suggest you use one, rather than trying to make a data structure that's inappropriate work.